# Is there a term for the principle governing the efficient spatial arrangement of items within a container?

Tags: neologisms

This question was prompted this morning (and yes, it's silly) when I opened the refrigerator to see (yet again) that *someone* had placed several short items on the top (tall) shelf, usurping space from items that can't be stored on any other shelf.

Maybe it's as simple as ***spatially efficient***.

(Yes, I realize I should maybe be posting this in *OCD dot stackexchange dot com*.)

Comment: I would used ***efficiently packed***.

Comment: I keep thinking we should use "tetris'd" but I'm pretty sure that's diluting a trademark.

Answer (score 6):

It's called, at least in Mathematics, simply *packing*.  See [Packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem) and, what I believe is the most common instance of the problem, [circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing).

Comment: Except in the mathematical use "packing" implies "optimal packing" (or near-optimal) because non-optimal packing is uninteresting. Thus, I'm not sure this jargon exports to the language generally.

Comment: It's called [_packing_](http://chemistry.osu.edu/~woodward/ch754/str_cp.htm) in chemistry as well, and applies generally to finding efficient spatial arrangements.

Comment: And the vastly more common "I am packing my suitcase" implies nothing about the efficiency of the packing.

Comment: @MSW it also means 'Good bye now' sometimes. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing a term from the U.S. Air Force, you might call it *[dense-pack](http://articles.philly.com/1986-08-20/news/26064949_1_mx-missiles-missile-silos-dense-pack)*.